# Integrate wordpress into your own website

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I already designed a layout, see the picture below.[image]

I want to integrate Wordpress into my layout, I downloaded Wordpress and already installed it: I put the `wordpress` folder inside XAMPP's `htdocs`. My website folder is `studentportal.com`.

I don't know how to start, I don't have any ideas to integrate Wordpress to my own customized site. I'm new to HTML, CSS, PHP, SQL, and Wordpress.

[image]

Comment: If you already have a template ready to convert then you are halfway there already. Go through tutorials like this:

http://www.sitepoint.com/create-your-own-wordpress-theme-from-an-html-template/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the wordpress(should mention db name password etc when it's asked or should customise wp-config file in your wordpress folder), you will be able to access the backend of your website through the *www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin*
There are different ways to create pages and posts(where we enter the data). So it's better to go through wordpress tutorials. I can help you by providing a tutorial file, from which I studied the wordpress(mail me, if it's required: vivek.kjk@gmail.com). There are many sites which provide the tutorials for wordpress. Just try Googling, you will find a good one for sure. So that you can learn the basics of wordpress. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to make a wordpress website with your layout.

1. You have to create a own Theme with your layout files
2. You have to change the name of your wordpress folder to studentportal.com